# Where are the bootsrap css files?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I create Webapp application using yeoman, Which includes sass.
In the index.html file I don't see link to the bootstrap css files.
I run it with grunt.
I am wondering, where are the bootstrap css files, and how does the browser recognize them?

Answer (score 0):

I realize that bootstrap style has been added to the main.css file.